# PHP echo HTML input variable outside heredoc

Tags: javascript, php, html

I include my HTML in PHP using heredoc, and I want to get the user input variable that is inside heredoc, and echo it out. I tried using $_GET["input"], but I got error undefined index:input
May I know how to get the input variable?

```
<?php
$htmlfile= <<<html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Seller Evaluation System</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-image:url("images.jpg");}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1><center><font color="darkblue">Seller Evaluation System</font><center></h1>

    <p><center>
        <script>
            function searchSite(){
            var input=document.getElementById("searchinput").value;
            var searchForm=document.getElementById("searchForm");
            searchForm.action="http://www.mudah.my/Malaysia/Electronics-3000/"+input+"-for-sale?lst=0&fs=1&q="+input+"y&cg=3000&w=3&so=1&st=s";
            searchForm.submit();
        }
        </script>

        <form method="get" action="ttt.php" id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" id="searchinput" size="33" placeholder="Search Electronic Gadgets..." autofocus>
        <button onclick="searchSite()">Search</button>
        </form>

        <p><label>Mudah<input type="checkbox" name="searchFrom" value="Mudah" checked/></label>
        <label><font color="grey">Lazada</font><input type="checkbox" name="searchFrom" value="Lazada" disabled="disabled"/></label>
        <label><font color="grey">Lelong</font><input type="checkbox" name="searchFrom" value="Lelong" disabled="disabled"/></label>
        <label><font color="grey">Ebay</font><input type="checkbox" name="searchFrom" value="Ebay" disabled="disabled"/></label></p>
    </center></p></br>
</body>
</html>
html;

echo $htmlfile;

$userInput=$_GET["input"];
echo $userInput;
?>
```

Comment: `<input type="text" id="searchinput" name="input"`

Comment: If `input` hasn't been passed in the url, it will not be set. using `$_GET['input']` will throw an error until after your form has been submitted with an element named `input` or you go to the url with `?input=whatever`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the input name "searchinput". But it could not be available if you not send the form, and you have to call it by "name" tag, noy by "id".

You can show it after send using Javascript, no PHP.

This works, but the form have to be processed by the same file, so "action" have to be empty. If not, you can get the GET parameters in the file process your form, in your example ttt.php

```
<?php
$htmlfile= <<<html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Seller Evaluation System</title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {background-image:url("images.jpg");}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1><center><font color="darkblue">Seller Evaluation System</font><center></h1>

    <p><center>



        <form method="get"  id="searchForm">
        <input type="text" name="searchinput" size="33" placeholder="Search Electronic Gadgets..." autofocus>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>


    </center></p></br>
</body>
</html>
html;

echo $htmlfile;

$userInput=$_GET["searchinput"];
echo $userInput;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for help, for the explanation and example, I'm new to web, therefore what I did is also bad and blur.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET[..]` takes the **name** of a form element. So in your HTML you need to include that:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="searchinput" size="33" placeholder="Search Electronic Gadgets..." autofocus>
```

Also note you only want to get the item when you submitted the form, you need to first check the GET exist:

```
// If we submitted our form with a element named "input", then echo
if(isset($_GET["input"]) {
    $userInput=$_GET["input"];
    echo $userInput;
}
```

That way the code only will run if the form was submitted.

Comment: Thanks, I've add in the if else. It works fine for now.